# Basic Asciidoc linter

Tags: asciidoc

I am using intellij for writing asciidoc documentation. It gives me basic linting messages like "use = instead of # for titles".

But this works only in intellij, I want the same level of linting also in my pipelines.

I googled, and there is [vale](https://github.com/errata-ai/vale/issues/161) which gives me things like spelling.

But is there a linter I could use in my pipelines that only give me basic syntax linting as intellij does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a standalone linter for Asciidoc. For CI, the best available tool is to run `asciidoctor` and capture any warnings it emits. That's not what you want since Markdown markup that is not understood becomes content in the output.

The [Asciidoc Working Group](https://asciidoc-wg.eclipse.org/) intends to produce a language specification and reference parser that would make it much easier to create a linter. There is no published timeline for the spec + parser work, but I hope to see progress before the end of 2023.